# macでVimのclientserverを有効化したいが，Error: invalid option: --with-client-serverというエラーが発生する．

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew

Homebrew経由でVimをインストールしたところ，clientserverが有効化されません．
さまざまなホームページに

```sh
brew install --with-client-server vim
```

を実行するように書いてあるのですが，実際に実行すると，

```
Error: invalid option: --with-client-server
```

とエラーを吐かれてしまいます．

```sh
brew install --with-clientserver vim
```

としても

```
Error: invalid option: --with-clientserver
```

とエラーを吐かれます．なお，Homebrewのバージョンは

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.2.16-46-g6b6efc5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 6b6efc5c8078a145711a38943931baaa144f3584
Last commit: 14 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: d7102825baf8116da0e12de7155427f6626cb700
Core tap last commit: 25 minutes ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_DISPLAY: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.bH0WKHQdKu/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 12
CPU: dodeca-core 64-bit kabylake
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3/bin/ruby
Clang: 11.0 build 1100
Git: 2.21.1 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 13.0.1
macOS: 10.14.6-x86_64
CLT: 10.3.0.0.1.1562985497
Xcode: 11.3.1
XQuartz: 2.7.11 => /opt/X11
```

の通りです．また，Vimのバージョンは

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled May 13 2020 16:25:25)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-700
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
略
-clientserver      +job               +persistent_undo   -toolbar
略
```

となっています．
clientserverを有効化する方法，あるいはclientserverとダウンロードする方法はあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

今のBrewのvimにはclientserverを有効にするオプションはないので、そのままでは無理だと思います。

以下にありますが
https://teratail.com/questions/178594

MacVimを入れてvimを使うなら有効になるかもしれません。